# Rails 3 dropbox help

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

i did a scaffold to make my DB and menus for group i need a drop down box instead of a text field

here is the code i have atm

```
    <%= form_for(@ad) do |f| %>
  <% if @ad.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@ad.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this ad from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @ad.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :ad_name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :ad_name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :group %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :group %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :description %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :description %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :credits %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :credits %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :image_url %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :image_url %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

if you can let me know how to change group to a pull down with selections it would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something like

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :group %><br />
  <%= f.select :group, Group.all.collect{|g| [g.id, g.name]} %>
</div>
```

That is to say, pass as second argument the list [id, label] of the  field you want to generate.

Comment: so then where would i define the g.id and g.name?

Comment: g is the item foe every iteration in Group.all and id and name is what I suppose to be the id and the name of each group. It depends on how you describe your Group model.

Comment: can you point me to an example im really new to Ruby and still learning

Comment: i finally found some info on what you posted thx for the help i think i can get it to work now

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried changing f.text_field to f.select?